# What breaks package compatibility between OpenRC and Systemd

Tags: systemd, snap, compatibility, openrc, artix-linux

I switched recently to Artix Linux with OpenRC as Init-system. I was using Manjaro before, which uses Systemd. Anyway, I was trying to install some packages I used on Manjaro that I have gotten from the snap-store. But I couldn't install it because of some systemd dependency.
I think was trying to onlyOffice and other stuff.

Comment: You need to at least provide an error message. Otherwise all we can offer is "something depends on some function provided by systemd", which I think doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Artix doesn't use snap but pacman, with Artix-specific repositories. Those are curated to include workarounds in case something depends on systemd. If a package is not included and it has hard dependance on systemd, tough luck. You can try asking for inclusion, which may or may not happen depending on if it is possible to remove the dependance or not.

Comment: @Destro As far as the rules of StackExchange go though, your question (contained only in the title) is unclear. It can be broadly answered as "the dependance on the specifics of systemd", mostly having to do with calling specific commands for service control, but also with systemd architecture, which far surpasses what an init system should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Titular Question

While this is indeed too vague for the specific answer the body of your question is seeming to ask, there is a specific answer to the question being asked in the title.

Packages depending on `systemd` and requiring such are going to contain service files placed where `systemd` expects them and uses these files to do things like run daemons, which is the typical means you may (or may not) have interacted with the init system of your specific distro. `OpenRC` being a different init system that approaches the running of daemons differently, among other differences, is not going to know where `systemd` init files would be, nor would it know what to do with them as they expect files to conform to different syntax. 
`Systemd` also brings with it a number of other functionalities and features that other init systems avoid, for better or worse. Therefore the answer to your titular question is that packages targeting or one the other generally are written such that they expect a specific environment which is not necessarily the environment another init system is going to provide.

### You Definitely Don't Need Snapd

`Snapd` is a package manager written to be useful across distributions, which is not necessarily a necessary function for the installation of whatever package you intended to install. Because it requires `systemd`, for what I do not know nor care to investigate, it is outside of the potential candidates for tools to install whatever package you intended to install with it.

Instead you might try the similar, not `systemd`-specific, `flatpak`. 
It is about the same thing, though it's claimed to be safer and is just as hungry for space on your system as it too installs all the dependencies it needs in a sandboxed environment. OnlyOffice is definitely available via the `flathub`,
which also describes the installation process and setting ups its repos, etc.

You can also use `pacman -Ss [whatever]` to check Artix's repository for the package (it just might be there). 
On Artix's wiki there are instructions for enabling additional repositories, including some of Arch's, which may provide you with what you need already.

Being based on Arch and using `pacman` means you can also use the AUR to access the packages in question. You will need to install an AUR helper such as `yay` or `paru`, then you can use the AUR helper in a manner similar to `pacman` to install whatever you want from the AUR.

Or you can find the git repository associated with the project (probably exists) and follow the instructions of its `readme.md` to build it from the source. Moving into the more niche and specific Linux distributions such as Artix, you should probably become comfortable with this process as it becomes more necessary the deeper into the rabbit hole you go where smaller teams are unable to keep huge repositories maintained for free and without even much in the way of thanks let alone help. 
Generally this will amount to a `git clone [repo url]`
followed by a `make` in the directory and another `sudo make install`,
which is not all that daunting
when you have the things you need, like `gcc` and `make`, already installed.